# Prerender htaccess for subdirectory url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, prerender

This is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "**************"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

        # Proxy the request
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://service.prerender.io/http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [P,L]


        RewriteRule ^ /index.html 
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I have done these in Angularjs-

```
<head>
    <meta name="fragment" content="!">
</head>

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

**My url is look like-**

```
https://www.{Hostname}/{folder-name}/ (BaseURl)
```

When I hot on below url it will redirect me on 404

```
https://www.{Hostname}/{folder-name}/category/category-name
```

Can Anyone help me out of this htaccess problem?

Answer (score -1):

You will want to make sure the Prerender config runs before this section of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Your .htaccess might look like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "**************"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

        # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
        RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff|\.svg))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/https://%{HTTP_HOST}.com/$2 [P,L]
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

If that doesn't fix the issue, feel free to send us an email at support@prerender.io with some more information so that we can help!

Comment: Can you please explain in detail step by step?

Comment: Just remove those 3 lines and add them back at the end of the file after the prerender section of the code. I will update my answer.